# How do I compile OpenMM?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I am installing OpenMM following the installation instructions found in the [OpenMM Users Guide](http://docs.openmm.org/7.3.0/userguide/introduction.html).

Info: Testing can not be completed because I have only 62% test targets completed. See bellow.

**Problem description**

`make install` (or `sudo make install`) gives the following message:

```
(base) bcramer@schrodinger:~/build_openmm$ make install
[ 62%] Built target ApiWrappers
[ 62%] Built target OpenMM
 ..............etc..........
[ 62%] Built target TestSerializeDrudeLangevinIntegrator

make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so', needed by 'libOpenMMCudaCompiler.so'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7253: recipe for target 'plugins/cudacompiler/CMakeFiles/OpenMMCudaCompiler.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [plugins/cudacompiler/CMakeFiles/OpenMMCudaCompiler.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Based on the error, I used:

```
stat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so
stat: cannot stat '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so': No such file or directory
```

After this I used:

```
sudo apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so
```

This gave the response:

```
libnvrtc9.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so.9.1
libnvrtc9.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so.9.1.85
nvidia-cuda-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so
```

When I ran

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

the file `libnvrtc.so` was not present in the indicated directory.

I included the following path in the `bash` environment in order to include `libnvrtc.so`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64/stubs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The file `libnvrtc.so` is present in `/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64`.

If I run `stat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so` again, I keep receiving the message:

```
stat: cannot stat '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so': No such file or directory
```

Question: How can I solve this problem in order to make `make install` work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install the [corresponding packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libnvrtc.so) with

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-dev libnvrtc9.1
```

If above fails I'll suggest to remove CUDA from `/usr/local/cuda-9.2` for more reproducible results.